# Drupal6 - Read Custom Field From a Page Inside A Block (that's on that page)

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

We have a Page that we have given a custom header text field.

For example...

- Title: Fruits
- Custom Header: We sure love fruits.
- Body: Apples, Bananas, Cucumbers, Durians, ...

In the page template there is a custom region where we've placed a block to display the "Title" and "Custom Header" like so

[custom_header_region]

- Fruits : We sure love fruits

[main body]

- Fruits
- Apples, Bananas, Cucumbers, Durians, ...

So, my question is this: inside that [custom header region], if we have a View with a Display as Block, how can we display those custom variables from the page that the block is on?

I would prefer to not have to install extra modules to get this working, but if it's completely necessary that's okay too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a view and give it an argument.
2. Select node id as the field for the argument
3. Set the configuration to "provide a default argument". The default argument should be to get the node ID from the URL if none provided.

You'll want to set another filter on this too that will limit it to only the content type that this design is in use (blog, whatever..) and limit the result to display 1.